# Should I flush ServletOutputStream every time I write to it?

Tags: java, jsp, exception, outputstream

I am getting following error in my AttachedFiles.jsp page:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/da8] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:213)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:194)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.AttachedFiles_jsp._jspService(AttachedFiles_jsp.java:786)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
```

My previous version had:

```
fileIn.close();
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

right after while loop, but I thought it is a good practice to place closing of all objects in finally block.
I also read that close() also flushes the OutputStream.

After I made this change I am getting above error :/

AttachedFiles.jsp

```
    FileInputStream fileIn = null;
    ServletOutputStream outStream = null;
    try 
    {   
        File fileToDownload = new File(file);

        response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
        String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
        if(fileName == null) fileName = "";

        String disHeader = "Attachment; Filename=\""+fileName+"\"";
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);
        fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);
        outStream = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] outputByte = new byte[(int) fileToDownload.length()];

        //copy binary contect to output stream
        while(fileIn.read(outputByte) != -1)
        {
            outStream.write(outputByte);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            outStream.close();
            if (fileIn != null)
                fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

if so, should I flush inside while loop , right after writing to outputStream?

Comment: I would argue that since you didn't open the stream that is it not yours to close.  This is perhaps more true given that you've embedded all of this in a JSP - a questionable practice in and of itself.  The flush is not needed at all - once control leaves the JSP the writer/stream will be flushed.  The only time I've used flush is for partial updates during processing.

Comment: Never flush inside a loop. Your copy loop ignores the value returned by `read(),` which should be provided as the third parameter of `write()`, along with a zero offset parameter.

Answer (score 0):

JSP compiles into a Servlet. It already prepares it's implicit objects in the resulting Servlet:

- request
- response
- out   (PrintWriter)
- session
- application
- config
- pageContext
- page

You can use out to write. But out is a Writer and as so it writes characters. You might want to write binaries.

It would be cool if you rewrite your code into a **Servlet**. It would be cleaner.

Otherwise, to solve inside a JSP, evereything one can say here would be a hack... Won't be cool.

- You could insert a explicit "return;" after doing the writing.
- You could try to clear buffers and reset internal state.
- Add crazy catches arround your jsp
- Al least, not too hacky, add <%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %> to assure JspWriter will not be created for the page.